# Optimizing iteration through linked lists

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, linked-list, iteration

I have a data structure composed of several `std::lists`, each sorted by a specific criterion. When a new item is inserted into this data structure, there is a need for a reference item already in this data structure. Also all the items between the reference and insertee need to be collected into sets.

According to the profiler, this insertion is the bottleneck of the entire program. Here I present a simplified version of my insertion method.

[image]

```
upperReferenceSet_.clear();
lowerReferenceSet_.clear();
for (int objective = 0; objective < nObjectives_; ++objective)
{
    const  Real referenceValue = reference_->value(objective);
    const  Real  inserteeValue =  insertee_->value(objective);
    const bool lower = referenceValue >= inserteeValue;
    const  int directionTowardsInsertee = lower ? -1 : 1;
    Iterator it = referencePositions_[objective];

    ReferenceSet& referenceSet = lower ? lowerReferenceSet_:
                                         upperReferenceSet_;
    const  auto comparison = lower ? [](Real a, Real b){return a >= b;}:
                                     [](Real a, Real b){return a <= b;};

    while (comparison(it->value(), inserteeValue))
    {
        referenceSet.insert(it->individual());
        std::advance(it, directionTowardsInsertee);
    }

    lists_[objective].insert(it, Node(insertee_, inserteeValue));
}
```

Each list is of type `std::list<Node>` where the Node is defined by:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node(Individual* ind, Real val)       :individual_(ind),value_(val){}
    const Individual* individual() const  {return individual_;}
    Real value() const                     {return value_;}

private:
    Individual* const individual_;
    const Real value_;
};
```

The `Individual` is an entity which has `n` values (objectives), where each value can be accessed by an `Individual::value(int index)` member function. There are `n` lists, each containing the same set of `Individuals`, each sorted by one objective (value). Also the objective pertaining to that list is cached in the node and can be accessed by the `Node::value()` member function.

I would like to ask how can I make this method faster. I suspect that there are three sources of slowness:

1. The access to reference sets indirectly using a C++ reference.
2. The use of lambda functions which produce another indirection.
3. The use of `std::advance` just to perform one step.

I am thinking of refactoring the function to pass the data structure **in two passes**, first for the upper reference sets and then for the lower ones. This would solve all three problems.

I am hesitating since it would result in some code duplicity. Also I am curious about any opinions on my theories and my code.

Comment: Ending your identifiers with `_` makes very unreadable `->` expressions...

Comment: I am trying to follow a convention of ending the names of private members with an underscore. This is actually a Google coding guideline http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Variable_Names#Variable_Names and although it is arguably ugly and needs some getting used to, for me it actually improved readability. I should have mentioned that the function is a member.

Comment: I see. Also, you should probably elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish, what `objectives` are, etc.

Comment: If you want to maintain sorted lists, consider using a skip list, heap, or tree instead.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: The google style guide for c++ is a know terrible style guide. Find a better one.

Comment: @LokiAstari This is interesting. I actually never questioned that guide. Could you provide some alternative? Do you use some predefined style guide?

Comment: @200_success I think the linked list is the fastest solution in this case, since you know exactly the position where to insert.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: [C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B004ISL6I0/?tag=stackoverfl08-20) Every company you go to will have its own style guide and you must learn to adapt to the style of the company. Getting a change in a guide once is established is an uphill battle.

Comment: Lambdas are particularly good at being inlined by the compiler when they are not capturing any variables. I would be surprised if there were actually any indirection occurring where your lambdas are called at all.

Comment: Consider passing the parameters to the lambdas by const & to avoid making copies.

Comment: Maybe consider using std::generate to build your reference set instead of your while loop. With full optimizations turned on in your compiler you might be able to get the loop unrolled a bit by using std::generate, and who knows, maybe that will give you a performance boost.

Comment: Your can replace `lists_[objective].insert(it, Node(insertee_, inserteeValue));` by `lists_[objective].emplace(it, insertee_, inserteeValue);`, but I doubt that you will have any relevant performance gain.

Comment: Replace your sorted lists by sorted arrays. Have those arrays actually bigger sized to avoid resizing them on each change. Your performances will skyrocket, not a single doubt.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested this solution, but I believe that your code could be simplified by using a `reverse_iterator`.

```
upperReferenceSet_.clear();
lowerReferenceSet_.clear();
for (int objective = 0; objective < nObjectives_; ++objective)
{
    const  Real referenceValue = reference_->value(objective);
    const  Real  inserteeValue =  insertee_->value(objective);
    const bool lower = referenceValue >= inserteeValue;
    Iterator it = referencePositions_[objective];
    if (!lower)
    {
        it = std::reverse_iterator<Iterator>(it);
    }
    ReferenceSet& referenceSet = lower ? lowerReferenceSet_:
                                         upperReferenceSet_;

    do
    {
        referenceSet.insert(it->individual());
    } while (it++->value() != inserteeValue);

    lists_[objective].insert(--it, Node(insertee_, inserteeValue));
}
```